# IFRAME not loading in parent frame when called from HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We have 1 IFRAME present in asp page. And 1 HTML page where we have redirected to the parent IFRAME on click of anchor tag using angular.js.

In HTML page we have code as given below present inside anchor tag,

`ng-click="seeDetail(); ">` Go to parent Iframe

In javascript function `seeDetail()` we have code as shown below,

```
var url = "./PageToBeLoaded.asp";
parent.document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME").item("frameID").src = url;
```

On call of this statement in javascript we need the URL to launch in parent IFRAME.However instead of loading in the parent IFRAME its loading in the HTML page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used ng-href tag with target attribute and it worked fine. Provided the URL to the ng-href and the frame name to the target attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.  You're looking in the parent, finding the iframe, and setting the `src` of it, which is probably the current iframe.  I think what you're looking for is `parent.location.assign(url)`.

Comment: Used the parent.location.assign(url). The page is launching ,however the previous HTML page is disappearing.

Comment: That's what you said you wanted, wasn't it?

Comment: Ya. However the HTML page should be visible and in the below frame the asp page should load.

Comment: You're trying to append the content of the page to the current page?